# Assemblyscript Class Inheritance - Type Casting

Tags: class, casting, assemblyscript

Is there a way to cast from a base class into a derived one?

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}

const b = new B()
const a:A = b //casts to base class ok
const b2:B = a //Error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in Assemblyscript this is called **upcasting**.

Currently the only way to achieve it is by using `a as B` syntax.

```
const b2:B = a as B   //correct
```

Other syntax is currently not supported

```
const b2:B = a        //incorrect - no implicit cast
const b2:B = <B>a     //incorrect - no angle brackets
```